# Block overriding with template file doesn't work

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

The Drupal version I'm using is v7.34. I'm using sub-theme created from Bootstrap as base theme.
My problem is, I want to override the "User Login Block" and put it in the header region (top bar), so I create these file in **templates** folder in my sub-theme:

1. **page.tpl.php**

   `//this simply do
   print render($page['header']);`
2. **region--header.tpl.php**

   `$search_block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search');
   $login_block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login');
   print render($search_block); 
   print render($login_block);`
3. **search-block-form.tpl.php**

   `//this copied from base theme and only modified some html tag`
4. **block--user--login.tpl.php**

   `//this simply print out some simple text
   print ("blahhhhhhhhhhhhhh");`

The result is, only search block is rendered as override, and the login block is rendered as default block, not rendered as the one I override.
I did some search but nothing matches my fault.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Answer (score 0):

**To Alter User login block**

- Find the template.php file for the theme you're working on. Should be in the root of the theme folder for your theme
- Assuming the "yourthemename_hook" function does NOT exist, at the bottom of your template.php file insert the following code:

> ```
> function yourthemenamehere_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
>    $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
>      'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
>      'render element' => 'form',
>    );
>    return $hooks;
>  }
> function yourthemenamehere_preprocess_user_login_block(&$vars) {
>   $vars['name'] = render($vars['form']['name']);
>   $vars['pass'] = render($vars['form']['pass']);
>   $vars['submit'] = render($vars['form']['actions']['submit']);
>   $vars['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($vars['form']);
> }
> ```

- Now create a directory inside your theme's directory called "templates" (assuming it doesn't exist already)
- Then create a php file inside that folder called: "user-login-block.tpl.php"
  Inside this file, put the following code:

> ```
> <div id="user-login-block-container">
>   <div id="user-login-block-form-fields">
>     <?php print $name; // Display username field ?>
>     <?php print $pass; // Display Password field ?>
>     <?php print $submit; // Display submit button ?>
>     <?php print $rendered; // Display hidden elements (required for successful login) ?> 
>   </div>
>   <div class="links">
>     <a href="/user/register">Create an Account</a> | <a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

- **CRITICAL STEP** as an admin on your website, navigate to "admin/config/development/performance" and click "clear all caches" -- if you don't, then these changes won't display on your website
- Modify the html markup inside "user-login-block.tpl.php" to your heart's content, and don't forget that you can also add those css classes to your main style.css file (AFAIK)

Comment: Hi Pravin, the method you showed me, it worked, but I didn't find document like this in drupal.org.
Is it official way? And what's different between two methods: **1. Yours**     **2. Use block--[module]--[delta].tpl.php**   ?  When each should be used? Thanks for your help.